# Yii2 - how to change structure of existing widgets?

Tags: php, html, yii2

Using this code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>
```

would return a specific HTML containing a set of divs, text etc.
[image]

Let's say I don't want to print out the label "Username" Above the input field, and maybe I want to add some HTML code for this input (maybe a div next to the input field..) what is the best way to do this?

Do I need to edit the class/file that is actually responsible for the output of this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field above the 'username' is label you can change it by chaining `lable()` function

```
<?php $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput()->label('Add your lable here') ?>
```

Please click [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html#label()-detail) link for more detail

Comment: Thank you, done some more research about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016554/hide-label-for-input-field

Comment: You are welcome :) Good to know that you did more research (y).